# Change img in slick dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slick.js

Customer want change slick dots images. So I created block with his downloaded images and hide them. After that I get img src and create

```
new Image()
```

with src from hidden block. Add img to li, create new array with objects with key for 'hover' and 'default' image.

```
$('.slick-dots li').each(function(i, e) {   
  var img = new Image();

  img.src = _images[i].normal;
```

_images - array with objects. Each value have one object. Each object have default and hover key with different src
    So i have smth like this

> [ {'normal': 'src', 'hover': 'src'}, {'normal': 'src', 'hover':
>   'src'}, {'normal': 'src', 'hover': 'src'} ]

```
img.slickData = _images[i]; 
    img.setHover = function(e) {
        this.src = this.slickData.hover;
    };
    img.removeHover = function(e) {
        this.src = this.slickData.normal;
    };
    $(this).on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        $('img' ,this).attr('src', img.slickData.hover)
    });
    $(this).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        $('img' ,this).attr('src', img.slickData.normal)
    });
    $(e).append(img);
});
```

}

Hover work. But problem is that I don't know the rigth way how to catch swipe and clickable events and change image to 'hover src'

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: It would be really helpful to make a [mcve].

Comment: _“I don't know the rigth way how to catch swipe and clickable events ”_ - the documentation lists all the events slick provides. You probably want to look into the events beforeChange/afterChange and swipe.

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe, thank you. This is almost what I want. But only swipe works as it's should be - immediately changes src to default img in previous and change src to hover in active dot. 
After works after animation is complete and then change src. Before do the same but in reverse.

I do something else, but swipe is the most incomprehensible question:

```
$('.slick-prev, .slick-next').on('click', function(){
    changeIcons() // when click next\prev
});
$('.services_slick').on('swipe', function(){
    changeIcons() // when swipe
});
changeIcons() // when page is loaded
function changeIcons(){
    var dotIndex = $('li.slick-active').index();
    $('.slick-dots li img').each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('src', _images[i].normal)
        $(this).parent().removeClass('services_icons_hover')
    });
    $('li.slick-active img').attr('src', _images[dotIndex].hover)
    $('li.slick-active').addClass('services_icons_hover');
}
```